# How to automate Adobe Acrobat Pro from .NET application?

Tags: .net, com, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I am creating a PDF document from a .NET application (written in C#) that serves as a "table of contents" to some other documents (using hyperlinks).
In order for the user to be able to search in all documents at once, we're creating a search index/catalog of all the linked documents (which all happen to be in the same directory).
To make things even easier, we also add a form button to the TOC that brings up the "Advanced Search" dialog. Nothing too complicated, in other words.

How can I automate this process?
From googling, it seems that I can either create a folder script (in JavaScript) or directly interact with Acrobat using COM...?
Unfortunately, I have found very little documentation.

Edit: It seems like the Adobe PDF Library is exactly what I want, but it also seems ridiculously expensive. But maybe the Acrobat SDK would be an OK solution? We already have Acrobat Pro licenses, requiring Acrobat to be installed wouldn't be a problem.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: "Ridiculously Expensive" is Adobe's middle name.

Comment: Clarify what you are trying to achieve. It seems like you want to be able to search through pdfs as if they were text, or are there more UI-ish specifics you're after?

Comment: @Davesoft The clarification can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127552/how-to-associate-search-catalog-file-pdx-with-pdf-document

Comment: "associate the .pdx file with my .pdf document, so it gets loaded automatically?"  Ah, so this was never a .net question afterall. Thought so. Good luck fighting adobe software :)