# How to associate search catalog file (.pdx) with PDF document

Tags: pdf, itext, acrobat, aspose, acrobat-sdk

Using a .NET application, I am trying to create a PDF "table of contents" that references other files, like one would distribute on a DVD etc.

For this purpose, I need a search index and catalog, so full-text search will work across documents.
I have been able to automate the construction of the index by copying an "old" .pdx file (the directory structure is always the same) and then calling JavaScript from C#:

```cs
var js = $@"catalog.getIndex(""{pdxFilePath}"").build('alert(""Hello"")', true)";

formFields.ExecuteThisJavascript(js);
```

But how can I associate the .pdx file with my .pdf document, so it gets loaded automatically?

In Acrobat, this is set in the "advanced" document properties:

[image: Acrobat document properties]

However, this is not accessible via the `info` or `metadata` properties of the document.
Apparently this is stored somewhere else, but I don't know enough about the PDF format to figure out how to access this data:

[image: PDF structure]

Any help would be highly appreciated. I could use both the Adobe SDK/JavaScript API or some other library (for instance, I know we already have an Aspose license).

Comment: Associating a catalog index file (PDX) with a PDF file is not supported in Aspose.PDF for .NET API, at the moment. However, a feature request with ID **PDFNET-42046** is already logged in our issue management system. We will let you know as soon as the feature will be supported. **PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @FarhanRaza Thanks. Is there a way to fix that using some low-level API?

Comment: We are afraid there may not be any workaround at the moment. We will be able to share any update as soon as the ticket will be investigated. Please be patient and spare us little time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here... I was able to solve this using [PdfSharp](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp).

The following code is compatible with PdfSharp 1.50.4845-RC2a.

`pdxFile` should be the name of the .pdx file including the file extension (e.g. "catalog.pdx"). I have only tested this with .pdx files located in the same folder as the PDF document, but I would assume that relative paths in general should work.

No guarantees that this is a perfect solution as I lack a deeper understanding of the PDF format, but this seems to work at least.

```cs
    private void SetSearchCatalog(PdfDocument doc, string pdxFile)
    {
        var indexDict = new PdfDictionary(doc);
        indexDict.Elements["/F"] = new PdfString(pdxFile, PdfStringEncoding.RawEncoding);
        indexDict.Elements["/Type"] = new PdfName("/Filespec");

        var indexArrayItemDict = new PdfDictionary(doc);
        indexArrayItemDict.Elements["/Index"] = indexDict;
        indexArrayItemDict.Elements["/Name"] = new PdfName("/PDX");

        var indexArray = new PdfArray(doc, indexArrayItemDict);

        var searchDict = new PdfDictionary(doc);
        searchDict.Elements["/Indexes"] = indexArray;

        doc.Internals.Catalog.Elements["/Search"] = searchDict;
    }
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?! It's an open source library and it gets the job done. I found zero other information on this matter, so clearly this would be helpful to somebody trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

/Search entry is not documented in PDF specification, probably is it an Adobe extension. 
You can use any library that supports low level COS objects (dictionaries, strings, numbers, streams, etc) but since the entry is not documented, you can only infer its structure from sample PDF files.

Comment: Thanks. I would be perfectly fine with that, but I don't know how COS objects (or any other low-level details of the PDF format) work. Can you recommend a (ideally free) .NET library that would support such operations? Any hints what I could google to find sample code? Thanks.

Comment: @TravelingFox for 3rd party library recommendations please ask here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ software recommendations are offtopic on SO.

Comment: Feel free to reply here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50930/pdf-library-for-modifying-low-level-cos-objects ;-)